# Compare previous value in loop and append to string if within tolerance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like below:

```py
word_list = '''
[{'bottom': Decimal('58.650'),
  'text': 'Welcome'
{'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
  'text': 'This'
},
 {'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
  'text': 'is'
},
 {'bottom': Decimal('77.280'),
  'text': 'Oliver'
}]
'''
```

that represents a series of words: `Contact Name is Oliver`, which is extracted from a PDF file. The `bottom` value is the distance from bottom to the top of the page.

The list is sorted by the `bottom` key:

```py
words = sorted(word_list, key=itemgetter('bottom'))
```

I am trying to iterate the list and each word to see if the word belongs on the same line - or it should be appended to a new line.

The way I am thinking to do this is to compare the `bottom` value in each loop, with a tolerance of `xx`. For example, the words `This` `is` `Oliver` is all on the same line within the PDF file - but the bottom value is not equal (hence the tolerance level).

## Expected output

**What I am trying to end up with, is something like:**

```py
[{'text': 'Welcome',
  'line:' 1
{'text': 'This is Oliver',
  'line': 2
}]
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    previous_element = word_list[i-1] if i > 0 else None
    current_element = word
    next_element = word_list[i +1] if i < len(word_list) - 1 else None

    if math.isclose(current_element['bottom'], next_element['bottom'], abs_tol=5):
       # Append the word to the line
```

I am a bit stuck in the above loop. I can't seem to figure out if the `math.isclose()` is correct and how to actually append the `line[i]` and the actual word to create a line sentence.

Comment: Please don't use built-in names (like `list`) as variables. Also, your variable `list` is actually a string and not a list, so `words = sorted(list, key=itemgetter('bottom'))` won't work.

Comment: @Ralf Good catch, thank you! Updated my question. The `word_list` in my actual code is being created by some other functions - but the output is like in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a `math` function; you could just check the threshold yourself. Maybe like this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

word_list = [
    {
        'bottom': Decimal('58.650'),
        'text': 'Welcome',
    },
    {
        'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
        'text': 'This',
    },
    {
        'bottom': Decimal('77.280'),
        'text': 'Oliver',
    },
    {
        'bottom': Decimal('74.101'),
        'text': 'is',
    },
]
word_list = sorted(word_list, key=lambda x: x['bottom'])

threshold = Decimal('10')
current_row = [word_list[0], ]
row_list = [current_row, ]

for word in word_list[1:]:
    if abs(current_row[-1]['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= threshold:
        # distance is small, use same row
        current_row.append(word)
    else:
        # distance is big, create new row
        current_row = [word, ]
        row_list.append(current_row)

print('final output')
for i, row in enumerate(row_list):
    data = {
        'line': i,
        'text': ' '.join(elem['text'] for elem in row),
    }
    print(data)
```

The output from this code is:

```
final output
{'line': 0, 'text': 'Welcome'}
{'line': 1, 'text': 'This is Oliver'}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want! However, I am trying to combine all the words on each row to create a line (and add this to a list). See my original question, under **Expected Output**. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
line_sentence_map = {}
tolerance = 5
line = 1
what_you_want = []
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if(i == 0):
        previous_line_threshold = word_list[i]['bottom']
        line_sentence_map[line] = []
    if(word_list[i]['bottom'] - previous_line_threshold > tolerance):
        what_you_want.append({"line":line,"text":' '.join(line_sentence_map[line])})
        line +=1
        previous_line_threshold = word_list[i]['bottom']
        line_sentence_map[line] = []
    line_sentence_map[line].append(word_list[i]['text'])
    if i == len(word_list) - 1:
        what_you_want.append({"line": line, "text": ' '.join(line_sentence_map[line])})
```

Here, what_you_want will give you what you want -

> [{'text': 'Welcome', 'line': 1}, {'text': 'This is Oliver', 'line': 2}]

Cheers!